# What is the reason of getting Model n_features is 11 and input n_features is 2 error

Tags: python, valueerror

```py
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
```

When I executed this, I got the error:

```py
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 11 and input n_features is 2
```

Can I get an answer for resolving this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share shapes of X1, X2

Comment: X1, X2  shape is (2000,2000) Created using np.meshgrid

Answer (score 0):

the classifier that you have trained expects 11 dimensions to the input. However, to predict, your np.array only has 2 dimensions.

Solution is to match the size to 11 by reshaping (or not reshaping). Eventually, np.array() which goes as an argument to your predict function should have 11 dimensions. Shape of every datapoint will be (1*11)